# Sorting mixed array according to types

Tags: php, arrays

Here is an example

```
Array
(
    [menu] => 11
    [parent] => 0
    [0] => 34
    [page] => 1
)
```

I want this to be sorted as this, all the values with numeric indexes should go to the bottom.

```
Array
(
    [menu] => 11
    [parent] => 0
    [page] => 1
    [0] => 34
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ksort()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

```
$arr    = array(
    'menu' => 11,
    'parent' => 0,
    0 => 34,
    'page' => 1
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
ksort($arr);
print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>
```

Will output

```
Array
(
    [menu] => 11
    [parent] => 0
    [0] => 34
    [page] => 1
)
Array
(
    [menu] => 11
    [page] => 1
    [parent] => 0
    [0] => 34
)
```

Comment: I dont need to sort the string keys also, just the numeric one only.

Comment: Calling `ksort($arr);` will sort all the keys. You can either use this or write your own sorting function and call it through `usort`. Btw, you don't need all the code I put above. That's just a demo. All you need to do is call `ksort`

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like something for [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).
Some sample code:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if (gettype($a) == "string" && gettype($b) == "int")
        return -1;
    else if (gettype($a) == "int" && gettype($b) == "string")
        return 1;
    else if (gettype($a) == "string" && gettype($b) == "string")
    {
        //String comparer
    }
    else if (gettype($a) == "int" && gettype($b) == "int")
    {
        if ($a == $b)
            return 0;

        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

$a = array(3, 2, 5, 6, 1);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key: $value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
<?php

$a = Array(
    'menu' => 11,
    'parent' => 0,
    0 => 34,
    'page' => 1,
);

function cmp($a, $b) {
    $ia = is_int($a);
    $ib = is_int($b);
    if ($ia === $ib) {
        return 0;
    } elseif ($ia) {
        return 1;
    } elseif ($ib) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

uksort($a, 'cmp');

var_dump($a);
```